# How to insert "Enter" in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this situation: 
An user inserts a text in a textarea. The user decides when to press Enter, so the text may look like this:

```
text text text text
text text
text
text text 
text

text text text text
```

This text goes into a database table and later is echoed in a div.
The problem is that when it is echoed it look like this:

```
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

What can I do to insert the text in the database in such a way that when is echoed it shoes the "Enters" as well ?

Comment: the "enters" (line-breaks) are most likely stored allright. But when you echo them, you do not see them. That is because browsers when interpreting HTML ignore control code. So, you need to either use the `<pre>` tag before the output, or transform yozur line breaks to ´<br />` tags.

Answer (score 4):

Use php `nl2br ()` function

```
<?php
  echo nl2br("YOUR TEXTAREA VALUE HERE", false);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi, nl2br is similar to the:

```
$details = my string with break lines given by user.

str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '<br>', $details);
Or 
str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '<br/>', $details);
```

It will catch all break lines then add the 
 same as the nl2br function.

Comment: almost the same: ne `nl2br()` function has the annoying tendency to add a carriage return after the `<br />` tag.

Comment: white-space:pre-line; did the trick. nl2br produces this effect: text <br> text <br><br>   ... it actually echoes <br> in the places where the user pressed Enter